# Rounding a numeric value upto 2 decimal places in javascript

Tags: javascript, rounding

i am trying to round a numeric value to upto 2 decimal places in javacript.
Please try to access the following url
https://www.jsnippet.net/snippet/1665/1/Rounding-a-value-upto-2-decimal-places

If you notice the code i am trying to round the following values 
3.225 , 4.225 and 5.225

If you notice the result,  3.225 is rounded of to 3.23 which is correct.
Also 5.225 is rounded of to 5.23 which is also correct but 4.225 is getting rounded of to 4.22 instead of 4.23

Can anyone please tell me how to fix this.

Comment: This is almost certainly due to truncation errors in the internal binary representation of numbers in JavaScript. The next problem is at 64.225, which rounds to 64.22. It doesn't round up again until you get to 82.225.

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
Number(Math.round(3.225+'e2')+'e-2');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a painful task on Javascript. From my experience, I do things like this:

```
function round(n, places = 2) {
  var epsilon = Number.EPSILON*1000;
  var exponent = Math.pow(10, places);
  var integral = Math.round((n+epsilon) * exponent);
  return integral/exponent;
}
```

`epsilon` is a very small number to compensate this behavior of floats in JavaScript.

Note: please don't use this function for sensitive data, is just a *very very* simple rounding function.

if you have to deal with sensitive data, use MathJS as user **King** suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Use the mathjs library, provided [here](http://mathjs.org/). The round function provided by this library is more precise than the builtin library. I've already tested your code using it and it works!